# Returning highest DATETIME from row with particular column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select the highest DATETIME for a specific Request code:

[image]

This is my query I'm using:

```
SELECT SubmitTime 
FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] 
WHERE  SubmitTime IN (SELECT Max(SubmitTime) 
                      FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request]) 
       AND requestcode = 'FOREMAN';
```

MY issue is that my query above returns nothing. I think what it's doing is it's finding that the highest DATETIME in the SubmitTime column does not belong to a FOREMAN request code.

How can I get it to return the latest SubmitTime for a specific Request code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just simply select like this, if of course those times don't repeat within `requestcode`:

```
SELECT max(SubmitTime)
FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] 
WHERE requestcode = 'FOREMAN';
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put the `requestcode = 'FOREMAN'` predicate in the `WHERE` clause of your subquery:

```
SELECT SubmitTime 
FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] 
WHERE  SubmitTime IN (SELECT Max(SubmitTime) 
                      FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request]
                      WHERE requestcode = 'FOREMAN') 
       AND requestcode = 'FOREMAN';
```

This way, the subquery will return the `MAX(SubmitTime)` for this specific `requestcode`.

As I see it now, after having a second look, you don't need the subquery at all:

```
SELECT Max(SubmitTime) 
FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request]
WHERE requestcode = 'FOREMAN'
```

This is enough, if all you want to get is just the `Max(SubmitTime)` for `requestcode = 'FOREMAN'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the latest SubmitTime you can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SubmitTime 
FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] 
WHERE  requestcode = 'FOREMAN'
ORDER BY SubmitTime DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT *FROM   [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] 
WHERE SubmitTime = (SELECT max(SubmitTime) FROM [QTRAXAdmin].[qt_request] WHERE requestcode = 'FOREMAN')
```